# Is there a Perl Kafka consumer group implementation

Tags: perl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am creating a Perl stateless horizontally scalable microservice and was looking for a High Level Kafka consumer group implementation.

I found this library 
https://metacpan.org/pod/Kafka::Consumer
Which has some low level functionality but has lots of limitations

1. One must explicitly state the partition.
2. The return value of

   $consumer->fetch_offsets(
       $topic,                      # topic
       0,
       $group
   );
   is a HASH not usable in the:

   $consumer->commit_offsets(
               $topic,
               0,
               $offsets1,
               $group
           );
   method.
3. etc ...

In the newer versions of Kafka consumer groups are handled by solely by Kafka without the need for a Zookeeper client and so clients in Java, Python, Scala ... just state group ID and leave a default auto commit to handle offsets. The polling logic and connections can also be handled by t High level libraries in those languages e.g. https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python

It is possible to use these building blocks or fork to create a high level library but I think someone probably has already done the work.

Is there an open source Consumer Group implementation in Perl? and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Net::Kafka](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Kafka) - it is a Perl wrapper of [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) C library that natively supports modern Consumer Group protocol.

Comment: extremely cool, also mention that liberkafka is the basis for Kafkastreams KafkaSQL and and Python client and kafkacat